# Thymeleaf to Retrieve Host Name (Hidden)

Tags: thymeleaf

Is there a way to retrieve the hostname for the server Thymeleaf is running on?

I would like to display the first part of host name hidden on the page. To triage when behind a load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just get the hostname on the server-side and add it as a variable to the model in your controller, just like any other variable.

Something simple like:

**Controller code**

```
model.addAttribute("myHostName", SomeUtil.getHostName());
```

**HTML**

```
<th:block th:text="${myHostName}">[host]</th:block>
```